# How to run website forms in Excel without having to use Sendkeys?

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am trying fill out a form on a website using Excel VBA. I have created an InternetExplorer.Application, navigated to the page and looked up a bunch of data, using `If UserForm1.TC2.Value = True Then` or something like `PostCode = objIE.document.getElementsByName("ProjectFile-ProposalAddress-PostCode")(0).Value` and the like.

Afterwards, I navigate to a new page, and look to fill it out using my previous data.

And this is where I run into trouble. I want to tick a check box 'New Permit', and its code is;

```
<form id="document-form">
<div class="generate-form form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span>New Permit</span></label><div class="input col-sm-7">
<div class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: NewPermit" />
</div></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><span>Staged Permit</span></label><div class="input col-sm-7">
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: StagedPermit" />
</div>
```

Which has no name to lock into. I'm not a HTML expert, but there is some more code that refers to this tickbox (I think)

```
 var model = {  "NewPermit": null,   "StagedPermit": null,  "AmendedPermit": null,
```

etc.

I have run a loop through the code using `.getElementsByTagName("Span")` with various `.tagName` etc. The following results is for the New Permit box:

`.tagName` = Span

`.outerHTML` = New Permit

`.outerText` = `.innerHTML` = `.innertext` = New Permit

`.isContentEditable` = False

`.tostring` = [object HTMLSpanElement]

`.ID` = ""

This is behind a password log in, and I cannot post the link publicly. But can work through PM etc to get to the answer.

Comment: How about something like `For each element in .getElementsByTagName("Span") | If element.outerHtml = "New Permit" Then element.Checked = True | Exit For | Next`

Comment: Run Time Error 438

object doesn't support this property or method.

I think you are running into `.isContentEditable = False`

but I do not know enough HTML to know

I also tried `element.click` from the span tag.

finally, I have to use `If element.outerHtml = "<span>New Permit</span>"` to get that statement to fire, which I think is why the `.click` fails

Comment: a few more up-votes and I think I can put a 50 rep bounty on it :)

Comment: what about `getElementsByTagName('input')` or `getElementsByTagName('checkbox')` then use the `Checked` method. The way I suggested before may not actually be grabbing the actual checkbox element.

Comment: Scott, you are a champion. I have tried for days to get this to work on various websites.

The ('input') version worked.

I am a man of my word, and will pay a bounty for this. Please PM me (IDK how yet on this site) and I will sort something out

Comment: No worries on the bounty, just happy you got it to work. :) Happy trails

Comment: how do I turn your comment into an answer for this?

Comment: (We prefer a succinct, non-chatty tone here, especially for titles. If my summary of the title isn't accurate, please feel free to tweak further).

Comment: @halfer - I am not the OP, but I remember the OP originally asking to be *saved from having to use SendKeys* ... not how to use them to fill out the form.

Comment: Thanks @Scott, I'll edit again.

Comment: Actually, its more how to run the website without a defined label or name tag to access the variable in HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getElementsByTagName('input')` and then use `Checked = True`

```
Dim element as Object
element = getElementsByTagName('input')
element.Checked = True
```

*assumes checkbox is the only input element on the page. If not, make a loop and identify the desired checkbox*

Comment: This actually works really well, as I have to edit other inputs later, some as textboxes. By using your suggested `if .outerhtml = XYZ` i can loop through and edit all the different things I want to.