# VBA to login a website, click a link on the loaded web page and navigate further

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I am implementing a `VBA` code to auto-login to a website, then after login is successful, I need to auto click a `button/link` on the page and from there fill in another form and submit it. So far the code works for entering the login information and clicking submit.

But from there on, the code doesn't click any link or button to proceed further. I don't receive any error upon debug. The code does not do anything after login.

**Note:** I am new to `VBA`, and need to implement this soon.

Here is the code I'm working on:

```
option Explicit

Public Sub Login_3_Website()

Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
'Dim oHTML_Elements As IHTMLElement
Dim oHTML_Elements As Object
Dim oHTML_Button As IHTMLButtonElement
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As IHTMLDocument
'Dim Element As HTMLLinkElement
Dim Element As Object
Dim elements As Object
Dim HTMLDocs As HTMLDocument
Dim sURL As String

'On Error GoTo Err_Clear
sURL = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, "B").Value
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
oBrowser.Silent = True
'oBrowser.timeout = 20
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do
' Wait till the Browser is loaded
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document

HTMLDoc.getElementById("login_username").Value = "aaa@gmail.com"

HTMLDoc.getElementById("login_password").Value = "1234"
For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")
If oHTML_Element.ID = "login_button" Then oHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next oHTML_Element

With oBrowser
Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop
End With

'Set HTMLDocs = oBrowser.document
'Set elements = HTMLDocs.getElementsByClassName("quick-access-trigger btn")
'Element.Click
'Next
Set Element = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("div")
For Each oHTML_Elements In Element
If oHTML_Elements.innerHTML = "Quick access" Then
oHTML_Elements.Click
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Please help me with this code and give me a way to fix it. The link I need to click on the page loaded after login has this code :

```
<div class="quick-links-wrapper">== $0
<div class="quick-access-trigger btn">
<span>Quick access</span>
<i class="nc-icon-glyph arrows-1_bold-down">
::before
</i>
</div>
```

Comment: I do believe you cannot click on a <div>

I had a similar problem, solved here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126580/how-to-run-website-forms-in-excel-without-having-to-use-sendkeys
This recently worked too. sorry, do not know how to put code in comments
    Set objElementColl = objHTML.getElementsByClassName("btn")
    
    For Each objElement In objElementColl
        ExtractedName = objElement.outerHTML
        
        If InStr(ExtractedName, "click: save") > 0 Then
            objElement.Click
            ExtractedName = 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

Comment: Why are you using `Visual Basic Script` ? That's a non-generic language that works only with IE, and I'm not sure that Edge supports it at all.
And user must accept execution of dangerous scripts on his computer, so that's a bad way for making public websites...

Comment: @BryanDavies Thank you for replying. I will try adding this code and executing it. Will let you know if it works.

Comment: @ClementNerma I'm new to VBA and I don't have much coding experience. While going through the current project, I came across a method to implement it using VBA and it worked, so I thought of continuing with it. I've read about Selenium which will work for other browsers as well. But I have a deadline and need to finish this soon.

Comment: You might want to check out some of the tools from the Analyst's Cave, there is something specifically for VBA web scraping that might help you: http://analystcave.com/downloads/vba-web-scraping-easy-scraping-from-excel/

Comment: @ClementNerma Can you suggest any other method or language for performing the above mentioned tasks?

Comment: Have a good poke around, I just noticed the link I sent is for a purchase (some of his stuff is provided without the need to purchase). That said, if you explore the site a bit you'll probably pick up a few nice pointers and maybe some sample code. Good luck

Comment: @BryanDavies - The code didn't work and I received debug error on ExtractedName = objElement.outerHTML. So I tried using oBrowser.Navigate to go to the particular page directly and it worked. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: @BryanDavies - Can you help me with auto-fill for captcha? In order to login to a website i can pass the username and password but the captcha needs to be added to proceed further.

Comment: isnt captcha designed to stop this?

Comment: @BryanDavies - yes I know, but is there any way to login ?

Comment: i think breaking captcha is a little beyond my skills

Comment: @Tim Williams - Can you help me to auto-fill captcha using VBA? I need to login in to a website which requires a captcha code before submit.

Comment: @BryanDavies - After login, how do I navigate in the new loaded webpage to a link which is under <div> tag on the left side of the webpage? I tried using .navigate but it works only for few websites. For the rest it just returns back to the login page for login details.

Comment: @ryguy7272 - After the login, i navigate using .navigate to a link on the website. I need to fill a form on that page. But i cannot access the elements. I have used the same HTMLDocument and elements for the new webpage. Do i need to create new ones for the new page and will it be included in the same Sub or different? At present the code just navigates to the page and does not do anything further. I didn't receive an debug error also. Please help.

Comment: Anyone? how to perform the above in the same Sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the link below for some great ideas of how to do what you need to do.

http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-login-to-website-using-vba.html

Answer (score -1):

To answer to [@RD DR's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168079/vba-to-login-a-website-click-a-link-on-the-loaded-web-page-and-navigate-further?noredirect=1#comment63766403_38168079) :

`Visual Basic for Applications` (VBA) is a language that is only supported by IE, and I don't think even Edge supports it.

A better thing would be making your code in JavaScript, which is standard and cross-browser compatible. Your code will be more simple and works under many browsers, and you will find a lot of help in developper's communities.

Comment: The code in this question is **V**isual **B**asic for **A**pplications (VBA - look at the tags) which isn't the same as VBScript. Edge doesn't support VBScript, but that's not relavant to the question in any way

Comment: Sorry I mistaken the post, but that changes nothing. VBA is only supported by I.E. too. Sorry for the confusion -_-